# CORBA IDL to C++ - char vs. unsigned char?

Tags: c++, corba, omniorb

We're using OmniORB with our C++ server. Currently, when an object is specified as a `char` in the IDL file, it is translated to an `unsigned char` in C++. We want it to be just `char`. Is there something we can change to make this happen?

Comment: Yeah, configure your compiler to treat char as unsigned by default (i.e. `-funsigned-char`).

Comment: "Can I change CORBA IDL to C++ Mapping" - a phrase uttered by thousands of C++ programmers in the late '90s.

Comment: I don't know the details of OmniORB, but TAO (see http://download.dre.vanderbilt.edu) does use the C++ char type for an IDL char. About changing the IDL mapping, have a look at the new IDL to C++11 language mapping, that realizes the mapping people have talked about for a long time (see http://www.omg.org/spec/CPP11/), we implement it as part of TAOX11 (see http://swsupport.remedy.nl).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is implementation defined ([page 15 in the spec](http://www.omg.org/spec/CPP/1.2/)) what the IDL types `boolean`, `char` and `octet` map to.

[omniORB chooses to](http://sourceforge.net/p/omniorb/svn/HEAD/tree/trunk/omniORB/include/omniORB4/CORBA_basetypes.h):

```
...
typedef unsigned char _CORBA_Char;
typedef unsigned char _CORBA_Octet; 
...
```

You can change the omniORB sources, though I doubt that would be a good idea. Or you can accept that `CORBA::Char` does not represent the C++ `char` type.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `CORBA::Char` when calling functions that are direct CORBA calls and assigning return values  of such functions.

If you need to convert them to/from 'char' or 'unsigned char', a `static_cast` should do the job.